# Kendo Grid Template: missing ) in parenthetical

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have the following template in my Kendo Grid:

```
$("#Grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        // etc (type, transport, etc)
        batch: false,
        pageSize: self.gridPageSize,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        sort: { field: "Name", dir: "asc" }
    },
    dataBound: function (e) {
        var body = this.element.find("tbody")[0];
        if (body) {
            ko.cleanNode(body);
            ko.applyBindings(ko.dataFor(body), body);
        }
        $(".k-grid-edit").html("Edit");
        $(".k-grid-edit").addClass("btn btn-default btn-sm");
    },
    edit: function (e) {
        $(".k-grid-update").html("Update");
        $(".k-grid-cancel").html("Cancel");
        $(".k-grid-update").addClass("btn btn-success btn-sm");
        $(".k-grid-cancel").addClass("btn btn-default btn-sm");
    },
    cancel: function (e) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".k-grid-edit").html("Edit");
            $(".k-grid-edit").addClass("btn btn-default btn-sm");
        }, 0);
    },
    filterable: true,
    sortable: {
        allowUnsort: false
    },
    pageable: {
        refresh: true
    },
    scrollable: false,
    columns: [{
        field: "Name",
        title: self.translations.Columns.Name,
        filterable: true
    }, 
    // etc... (more columns)
    {
        field: "Id",
        title: " ",
        width: 80,
        filterable: false,
        template: '<button type="button" data-bind="click: runNow.bind($data,#=Id#)" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Run Now</button>'
    }, {
        command: ["edit"],
        title: "&nbsp;",
        attributes: { "class": "text-center" },
        filterable: false,
        width: 200
    }],
    editable: "inline"
});
```

I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical
*   return ((d.runNow || {}).bind($data)
```

The above error is seen in **FireBug** and comes from **kendo.web.min.js**

Do I need to escape the parentheses here or what? What's the correct way to write the template?

**EDIT**

I would also like to note that it seems there is no error until i click the "Edit" button.. that's when I get this error message. So probably my first guess about it being the template is not correct.. maybe there is some bug when using inline editing + templates?

Comment: `((d.runNow || {}).bind($data)` has an extra starting parentheses. Remove it.

Comment: @nemesv, it's from kendo. Please see I added more of my configuration above.

Comment: @Dandy, I can see that.. but why this is happening, I don't know. That is obviously minified code that the browser sees based on what I showed above.

Comment: I would also like to note that it seems there is no error until i click the "Edit" button.. that's when I get this problem.

Comment: @Matt, can you provide jsfiddle or plunkr? also try use `kendo.web.js` possibly error message would be more informative

Comment: Do you really using knockout also in your application? So the `click` binding is intended to work as the knockout click binding? Because kendo also comes with a binding framework which also has a click binding and I think this causes the confusion

Comment: @Grundy, I only have the minified one since I am using the free, open version (Kendo Core 2014.1.318).

Comment: @nemesv, I am indeed using Knockout.. in fact, I am using Durandal 2 and that of course includes Knockout.

Comment: What is `#=Id#`? It looks like something is treating the hash as the start of a comment, so it's not seeing the rest of the line.